# How to Start a Python Interpreter in a C Program

Tags: python, c, linux, embed

I was reading the [embedding guide](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html), which tells you how to embed static python methods and compile/run them in a c program. I got some static code to run but what I'm wondering, is that since it's possibly to embed a dynamic language in C, can you just force whatever is running in the process to pause and embed the whole python interpreter?

The goal here would be to run any methods that have already been defined in the C program from the python interpreter. It's not clear to me if it's possible to embed the interpreter so to make this happen. Is there a specific version to make this work?

The closest thing the guide talks about is a runtime argument being passed, where I'm looking for a way to suspend operations in the middle of execution until I enter a python statement.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way to suspend operations in the middle of execution
>   until I enter a python statement.

[Embedding Python in Your C Programs | Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8497/print) has this example:

```
void exec_interactive_interpreter(int arg, char** argv)
{
  Py_Initialize();
  Py_Main(argc, argv);
  Py_Finalize();
}
```